# Why does BigQuery load job statistics return query information?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

We've got some load jobs that scoop up files from GCS, and load them into BigQuery for analysis. We use the `JobConfigurationLoad` [class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobConfigurationLoad.html) in the BigQuery Java API to achieve this.

It works fine.

However, we've noticed that the `JobStatistics` [class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobStatistics.html) that is returned when the job finishes contains "query" and "totalBytesBilled" information.

[image]

If this is a load job, why does it return query information?

Comment: It is part of the job statistics, not of query statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is an error reporting details about the load job.  We've got an issue open internally as BigQuery load jobs should not be populating the query processing statistics (we're leveraging our query execution tree to assist with some load jobs).

It is worth noting that even though the processing stats fields are populated in the same way we report query analysis usage, these load jobs did not contribute any query analysis costs.

Comment: Thanks. It's worthing noting that how we found this bug was through the fact that one of our applications suddenly failed on the 18th Feb. The code used the "JobStatistics" object to determine if the job was a query or a load by calling "statistics.getQuery() != null", or "statistics.getLoad() != null". This worked fine. But then "statistics.getQuery()" starting returning an object even for load jobs! So it fell over. You may want to look at fixing that. Cheers.