# Why does BigQuery load job statistics return query information when using the Java SDK?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

We have an application built on top of the [BigQuery Java API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-bigquery) (we couldn't use the [newer BigQuery API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery), because at the time it was missing support for setting the [max billing tier](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/2012)).

I've asked this question once before on another Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690288/why-does-bigquery-load-job-statistics-return-query-information), but that was over 1.5yrs ago, and I feel this warrants a new question.

In a nutshell, when requesting the job statistics for a LOAD job ([API request to job.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load)) using the Java API, the `QUERY` field is now populated with `statistics.query.totalSlotMs`:

[image]

This was not being returned up until some time around the 18/19 September, which has subsequently caused issues in the application.

Why is a LOAD job returning query statistics, specifically `totalSlotMs`, if it's not actually a QUERY?

Comment: Can you submit a bug on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) with a sample job ID? Load jobs are modeled like queries, so they do use slots, albeit generic ones that don't count against slots in your project. The slot milliseconds is misleading to include in these stats.

Comment: Will do Elliot. The problem we have is that we just a check on that field to determine if the Statistics object is for a LOAD or QUERY (we have out own profiling for queries). Obviously, this now fails because the application thinks the LOAD job is a QUERY job ;-)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. This shows the limitations of my own knowledge... I would have assumed that there was some other way based on the response to tell what job kind it was. In any case, hopefully we can get it resolved soon, and thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there is not. The only way to determine what type of job it is, is to check `getQuery() != null` or `getLoad() != null` etc. There needs to be something like `getJobType()` which returns an Enum value IMHO. Also, having the different class/object names `JobStatistics1`, `JobStatistics2`,  `JobStatistics3` and  `JobStatistics4` is extremely confusing ;-)